How do I open the ./etc/ folder as root in VSCode?
how can I open a folder like /etc/ in VSCode via SSH and edit files using the editor instead of the terminal, such as 50-cloud-init.yaml?
I am aware that I can edit files in the terminal by adding sudo, changing permissions, or opening in VSCode, but I want to open the entire folder as sudo, edit and save without changing permissions in the terminal, etc. To save a file as root,
I use:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yy0931.save-as-root
For opening and editing a file or folder with a similar extension, what method or workaround should be used?
